# Floated buttons

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple floated button markup. I have some sort of problem with stacking, but I don't know what exactly causes that, only that it is related to "a" elements somehow.

I omitted `href` attribute only here for brevity.

```css
.fbutton {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  background: #3C0;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<a class="fbutton">Our review</a>
<a class="fbutton">All Features</a>
<a class="fbutton">Free Version</a>
<a class="fbutton">Full version</a>
```

This is what it looks right now.

[image]

I was expecting it to be in a staright line. If I use div elements everything is ok, but I would like to keep code to the minimum. Any suggestion?

Comment: jsfiddle example please

Comment: It works well, I couldn't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/toyaz/1/edit

Comment: The code snippet works for me on Firefox 36, Chromium 40 and IE 8.

Comment: Geez, I have no idea what is interfering with my code. Added !important to all lines, still the same stacking. JsFiddle indeed works. Have no idea....

Comment: You must have more CSS that is affecting `.fbutton` or `<a>`

Comment: Check the developer tools on Chrome, that would definitely help to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, I am editing a free template. That's why I tried important, to get rid of additional formatting sneaking in, but there is obviously still something.

Comment: Just in case anybody still reading and wants a good story: after debugging css for an hour I realized that wordpress added extra linebreaks after my "a" tags. I live WP:)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hshgjcjg/1/

**HTML**

```
<a class="fbutton">Our review</a>
<a class="fbutton">All Features</a>
<a class="fbutton">Free Version</a>
<a class="fbutton">Full version</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.fbutton {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background: #3C0;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: The OP's posted code snippet already works. Your answer doesn't add anything to the OP's current code.

Comment: Yes i know. This is how i started my answer with "This is works for me". I've just created a jsfiddle example. Do not understand why i was devoted.

Comment: "This works for me" is not a valuable answer, you deserved -1 mate.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the downvote is obvious: your code is just OP's one with small irrelevant changes. And "This is works for me" is a comment, not an answer.